# Get locale specific directory in My documents

Tags: c#, window, locale

I have my custom application that generates a directory in My documents path, after installation the application uses that directory, but i got an issue in Chinese windows OS, where my application folder name appears in Chinese, so is there any way i can get the file name properly in "en" or some wordaround so that i can that directory name at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean? If you create `MyApp` directory, it will show as `MyApp` regardless of locale. Maybe you have a bug in the code that creates the directory?

Answer (score 94):

Use the special folders in System.Environment

`var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
 var subFolderPath = Path.Combine(path, "sub folder");`

Comment: that will give path only upto MyDocuments, i am looking for the directory inside MyDocuments whose name is locale specific.

Comment: String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\yourFolder";

Comment: I'd use `Path.Combine()` personally, or at least `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`. Gotta think of Mono support :p

Comment: @Nyerguds exactly.

Answer (score 7):

```
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

then you can append folder name as

```
string folder ="\\YOUR_FOLDER_NAME\\";
```

Then append to you path as

```
String full_path=path+folder;
```

Comment: You should use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to append two parts of a path. It takes care of the \, you don't have to put any.